# Assigning numbers to category in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have this following dataframe:

| #ID | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1029 | 78 |
| 1229 | 89 |
| 1929 | 77 |
| 2124 | 100 |
| 3120 | 89 |
| 4145 | 84 |

I want to create this following dataframe:

| #ID | Classification | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1029 | Freshman | 78 |
| 1229 | Freshman | 89 |
| 1929 | Freshman | 77 |
| 2124 | Sophomore | 100 |
| 3120 | Junior | 89 |
| 4145 | Senior | 84 |

So the 'Classification' column assignment is dependent on the first digit of the '#ID' column. My original dataframe contains thousands of records, so creating a dictionary is not really an option. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can use a dictionary just to map the possible first digits, and then you can use `apply` like this:

```
classification = {
    '1': 'Freshman',
    '2': 'Sophomore',
    '3': 'Junior',
    '4': 'Senior'
}

df['Classification'] = df['#ID'].apply(lambda id: classification[str(id)[0]])
```

Which results in your desirable dataframe:

```
    #ID  Score Classification
0  1029     78       Freshman
1  1229     89       Freshman
2  1929     77       Freshman
3  2124    100      Sophomore
4  3120     89         Junior
5  4145     84         Senior
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is helpful. How would the code change if only a few IDs need to be assigned to 'Other' classification? For example, IDs 4225 & 4349 need to be assigned to 'Other' even though the first digit is 4?

Comment: You can create a list of those specific IDs (called `ids`, for example) and then run `df.loc[df['#ID'].isin(ids), 'Classification'] = 'Other'`

Comment: If my answer did help you, please remember to "Accept" it, so this question is marked as solved

Comment: I have done it now. Thanks. Thanks for your help.